# Install Gatsby in the /blog directory

Tags: github, gatsby, netlify

I created a Gatsby blog using the Netlify one-click button but wish to have my own home landing page using index.html and then then the Gatsby blog be built in the /blog directory of my site (example.com/blog)

I have looked into the config.js and gatsby-config.js files for settings to change the build location plus I have also tried a few different build commands in Netlify such as

Build command : gatsby build

Publish directory: public/articles

Can anyone help build this in a specific folder(directory) whilst leaving my own index.html in the root directory?

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this starter](https://github.com/cvluca/gatsby-starter-markdown) and have a read of [Gatsby tutorial Part 7](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/)

`gatsby-node.js`

```
const replacePath = path => (path === `/` ? path : path.replace(/\/$/, ``))
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
const path = require("path")

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `blog` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: replacePath(slug),
    })
  }
}


exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const postTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/postTemplate.js`)

  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(result.errors)
    }

    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: replacePath(node.fields.slug),
        component: postTemplate
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Here in `onCreateNode`, if the node's internal type is `MarkdownRemark`, a filepath is created with a base path of `blog`, and that new filepath is added to a new node field called `slug`.

This new field is now available in any graphQL queries.

So later in `createPages`, the new `slug` field is queried and used in the `createPage` path option.

So pages in your `src/blog` folder will remain to be served from the root, while posts generated by `MarkdownRemark` will be served from `/blog/`

Answer (score 1):

In gatsby-config.js add this

```js
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/blog`,
```

and while you building your app:

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to tell Gatsby where you want the file. Netlify just wants to know where your public folder is.

```
gatsby build --output-dir public/articles
```

You can either then move your own `index.html` file into the directory created (`public`), or have it already there*.

I would also recommend looking at letting Gatsby run your whole site, and create a static file for your homepage, then your build process is much simplier, and you can run it locally.

** Not sure if that is allowed, Gatsby may require an empty or non-exisiting folder to build into.*

Comment: There is an option in the config to have a prefix for blog posts I recall so they show as /blog but the rest of the Gatsby site is at / with all content related to the blog. Just want to have my own index.html homepage rather than using Markdown for my own custom homepage